# Error in Blackberry Webworks: Feature cannot be found in any extension

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

I got an Error when i try to run `blackberry Webworks project`

```
[ERROR] Feature cannot be found in any extension(blackberry.media.microphone)
```

**What i have done:**

I have used simple html file named as `login.html`

I didn't use any kind of audio file in my app,i have added the `feature` also as  below:

```
<feature id="blackberry.system" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="org.apache.cordova" required="true" version="1.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.find" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.identity" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.identity.phone" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.pim.Address" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.pim.Contact" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.io.file" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.utils" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.io.dir" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.app.event" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.system.event" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
  <feature id="blackberry.widgetcache" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
  <feature id="blackberry.media.camera" />
  <feature id="blackberry.ui.dialog" />
  <feature id="blackberry.connection" />
  <feature id="blackberry.bbm.platform" />
  <feature id="blackberry.invoke.card" />
  <feature id="blackberry.pim.contacts" />
  <feature id="blackberry.ui.contextmenu" />
  <feature id="blackberry.io.filetransfer" />
  <feature id="blackberry.io" />
  <feature id="blackberry.invoke" />
  <feature id="blackberry.invoked" />
  <feature id="blackberry.push" />
  <feature id="blackberry.media.microphone"/>

  <!-- Cordova API -->
  <access subdomains="true" uri="file:///store/home/user/voicenotes/" />
  <access subdomains="true" uri="file:///SDCard" />

  <!-- Expose access to all URIs, including the file and http protocols -->
  <access subdomains="true" uri="*" />

  <icon rim:hover="false" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
  <icon rim:hover="true" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />

  <rim:loadingScreen backgroundColor="#CFCFCF"
                     foregroundImage="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"
             onFirstLaunch="true">
    <rim:transitionEffect type="fadeOut" />
  </rim:loadingScreen>

  <content src ="login.html" />

  <rim:permissions>
    <rim:permit>use_camera</rim:permit>
    <rim:permit>read_device_identifying_information</rim:permit>
    <rim:permit>access_shared</rim:permit>
    <rim:permit>read_geolocation</rim:permit>
    <rim:permit>record_audio</rim:permit> 
    <rim:permit>access_pimdomain_contacts</rim:permit> 
  </rim:permissions>
```

I didn't figure it out why the error is happening!! Could anybody help me out @Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It means you are trying to use an incompatible API (microphone). The [microphone API](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.media.microphone.html) is supported on BlackBerry OS 5.0+ and PlayBook but not BlackBerry 10.

```
<feature id="blackberry.media.microphone"/>
```

The BlackBerry 10 Webworks SDK will correctly report that it does not recognize this feature because microphone is now an HTML5 standard.

For BlackBerry 10, you should use the [HTML5 standard getUserMedia()](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) to record using the microphone.

Comment: Adam Stanley +1 for your answer